# Issue with Kendo Grid Read action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo Grid to load data. In this particular scenario, I have to pass a large amount of data from Kendo Grid to Controller.

My Kendo grid read action was like this:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("BindJESummary", "JEDataView", new
{
    FilterQueryId = @Model.FilterQueryId,
    KnowledgeAccounts = @Model.KnowledgeAccounts,
    GLAccounts = @Model.GLAccounts,
    jeFilterTestingModel = Json.Encode(@Model.JEFilterTestingModelData)
}).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
```

This was working fine, but when the data is too large, this broke. It was not hitting controller. When we checked, Kendo was sending the large data in the URL.

[image: Data in URL]

How can I make Kendo to send the data in in Post request body?

Or, is there a better way to do post request from Kendo Grid?

Comment: your content length only 40, how can you say that is large data, lol.. the problem is you are using Json.Encode, have you tried removing that or try another library to serialize?

Comment: What does your controller action look like?

Comment: The answer is in your own question. Use POST. Why are you sending all this data to your controller in a GET (i.e. `.Read()`) request?

Comment: @DionDirza When only 40 is going with url. I haven't tried any other library. I will try that.

Comment: @Brett May, I have used Post only (Type(HttpVerbs.Post)).

Answer (score 1):

You can control max limit data by editing Web.Config

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
    <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000000" />
    </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

and if that doesn't help try this

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```